# linearize objective function

Tags: linear-transformations, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, piecewise-continuity, linearization

[Nonlinear objective function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNKzQ.png)

Hello everyone,

To be able to use following objective function in the software CPLEX, we must first linearize the function, because CPLEX cannot solve function that are non lineair in the decision variables. xj; yij and yjk are decision variables. Who can help? Taking the square root is not good, since this causes a too big input value for fj. How to perform a piecewise linearization on this?

the function to be linearized, is provided in the attachment.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In order to get a better help from people here, would be interesting if you provide your thoughts and where you got stuck.

Comment: Not so easy as far as I can guess. Piecewise linear interpolation is the easiest in one dimension: i.e. $y=f(x)$. From what I can see, you have many non-separable $z=f(x,y)$. Doable but not that easy (see [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2016/09/2d-sos2.html)). I think I would try a nonlinear solver first. Nowadays, we actually can solve significantly large models with large scale NLP solvers. I don't understand your remark about square roots and $f_j$ in this context.